# Make own rails search engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, search-engine

I am making a web application using ruby on rails.
My application has a database consist of study records.
A study record consist of String information: record number, descriptions...etc

I want to search the results and display them on my web application.
However, I must use my own search engine to search and return the result.
My thoughts currently is:

1. The search engine is a separate program
2. User input: string of keyword
3. My own search engine take the keyword and process the return
   output
4. Output: csv results (because I want to display this as a table)

Now the problem is:

1. How to make my own search engine like this in Rails?
2. How to pass input to that search engine
3. How do the search engine send output back to my rails application so that I can display the result as a table?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we expect you to have a go at your code first - and come to us with areas where you get stuck. We are happy to help, but aren't going to design or code your system for you - just help you debug or answer any specific questions. (by specific, think of questions that would have a "right answer").

Answer (score 1):

There is a

> Solr

with good gem

> sunspot

that adds a nice dsl to solr.

There is also another full text engine,

> ElasticSearch

with the

> tire gem

search engine in a Ruby script

> [Picky](http://florianhanke.com/picky/)